# Anatomy of <system.serviceModel>?

Tags: wcf

Could you please provide me with a brief breakdown of the system.serviceModel section in a WCF config file? What are the valid sub-sections, and what do they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731354.aspx

hint:  http://www.bing.com/search?q=system.servicemodel+schema